# More elegant way of getting array with distinct values

Tags: php, arrays, distinct-values

I have this array:

```
$array[] = [
      'a' => $a,
      'b' => $b,
];
```

The array contains of let's say 10 entries, $a can be in there with the same value many times and I need only one of those entries for a db insert.

I can't manage to get array_unique working as it throws

```
 array to string conversion
```

error when trying to use it like

```
 $result = array_unique($array);
```

I now made a little foreach loop that feels just wrong to do so:

```
    $z = [];
    foreach ($array as $x) {

        if (@!in_array($x['a'],$z)) {
            $z[] = $x['a'];
        }
    }
```

and I use $z for the insert thereafter.

Can someone point me in the right direction of how to distinct my array values?

Comment: Are you sure you do not mean `$array`, instead of `$array[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

(`$result = array_unique($array);` this didn't worked, because you have a multidimensional array!)

```
<?php


    //Example data
    $array[] = [
          'a' => 1,
          'b' => 1,
          'c' => 1,
          'd' => 2,
          'e' => 2,

    ];

    $array = array_map("array_unique", $array);
    print_r($array);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [a] => 1 [d] => 2 ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your array that is two dimensional, you would need:

```
$array = array_map('array_unique', $array);
```

Or if you don't need a two dimensional array, just use:

```
$array = [
      'a' => $a,
      'b' => $b,
];
```

And then: `$array = array_unique($array);`

Answer (score 0):

One thing not mentioned is that arrays are built in unique, if you can manage the keys for them yourself.  Associative arrays can only have the key once.  So I like to do is use the primary key or a unique identifier for the key.

You can't have an array with the same keys like this.

```
array(
     'a' => $a
     'a' => $b
)
```

Because the key `a` is already a unique identifier. If you follow.